# Insert from for loop - add select option value to only one record

Tags: php

I have an insert happening in a for loop inserting 4 records into database.  I want to have only one of these new records get the value from a select menu in the form, contained in the variable $action. The menu appears only for one record on the form, depending on user selections.

Table structure is:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `pathway` (
  `pathway_pk` int(3) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `case_fk` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `level` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `pathway_allowed` char(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'n',
  `pathway_action_fk` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `comment` text NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `created_by` int(3) NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated_by` int(3) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`pathway_pk`)
)
```

The PHP:

```
$author_pk = $_GET['author_pk'];
$case_pk = $_GET['case_pk'];
$patient_pk = $_GET['patient_pk'];

$pathway_allowed = intval($_POST['allowed']);

$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actions']);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$pathway_comment = array();
foreach($_POST['comment'] as $comment) {
    $pathway_comment[]= mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
}
for($i=0, $count = count($pathway_comment);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $comment = $pathway_comment[$i];
    $query = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO pathway (             
           pathway_pk,
           case_fk,
           level,
           pathway_action_fk,
           pathway_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$case_pk',
           '1',
           '$action',
           '%s',
           '$comment')", $pathway_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n');

       $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

The rest:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#jMenu").jMenu();
$("select, input, a.button, button").uniform();


$("input:radio[id='allowed_0']").click(function() { 

$("#required_p2").remove();
$("#required_p3").remove();
$("#required_p4").remove();

if($(".p1_action").text().trim()==""){
$(".p1_action").append('<div class="required" id="required_p1"><select name="actions" id="actions"><option>Select an action for this pathway...</option></select></div>');
}

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].pathway_action_pk + '">' + data[i].action + '</option>';
    }
    if($('select#actions option').length == 1){
    $('#actions').append(html);
    }
});
});


$("input:radio[id='allowed_1']").click(function() { 

$("#required_p1").remove();
$("#required_p3").remove();
$("#required_p4").remove();

if($(".p2_action").text().trim()==""){
$(".p2_action").append('<div class="required" id="required_p2"><select name="actions" id="actions"><option>Select an action for this pathway...</option></select></div>');
}

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].pathway_action_pk + '">' + data[i].action + '</option>';
    }
    if($('select#actions option').length == 1){
    $('#actions').append(html);
    }
});
});



$("input:radio[id='allowed_2']").click(function() { 

$("#required_p1").remove();
$("#required_p2").remove();
$("#required_p4").remove();

if($(".p3_action").text().trim()==""){
$(".p3_action").append('<div class="required" id="required_p3"><select name="actions" id="actions"><option>Select an action for this pathway...</option></select></div>');
}

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].pathway_action_pk + '">' + data[i].action + '</option>';
    }
    if($('select#actions option').length == 1){
    $('#actions').append(html);
    }
});
});



$("input:radio[id='allowed_3']").click(function() { 

$("#required_p1").remove();
$("#required_p2").remove();
$("#required_p3").remove();

if($(".p4_action").text().trim()==""){
$(".p4_action").append('<div class="required" id="required_p4"><select name="actions" id="actions"><option>Select an action for this pathway...</option></select></div>');
}

$.getJSON('../scripts/get_pathway_actions.php', function(data){
    var html = '';
    var len = data.length;
    for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
        html += '<option value="' + data[i].pathway_action_pk + '">' + data[i].action + '</option>';
    }
    if($('select#actions option').length == 1){
    $('#actions').append(html);
    }
});
});


});

function validate(){
valid = true;

if ( document.form.comment_1.value == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter a comment for Pathway 1" );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

if ( document.form.comment_2.value == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter a comment for Pathway 2" );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

if ( document.form.comment_3.value == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter a comment for Pathway 3" );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}

if ( document.form.comment_4.value == ""){
    alert ( "Please enter a comment for Pathway 4" );
    valid = false;
    return valid;
}




return valid;
}

function delayer(){
window.location = "create_pathways.php?author_pk=<?php echo $author_pk; ?>&case_pk=<?php echo $case_pk; ?>&patient_pk=<?php echo $patient_pk; ?>"
}
</script>
<body>
<?php include('menu_bar.php'); ?>
<div class="settings">
  <div class="buttonn"> <a href="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], '?logout=true' ?>" class="buttonn">Logout</a> </div>
  <div class="buttonn"> <a href="change_password.php?author_pk=<?php echo $author_pk; ?>" class="buttonn">Change Password</a> </div>
</div>
<div class="title">Create Pathways for Level 1<span class="message"><?php echo $message; ?></span></div>
<div class="top_form">
  <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <table width="182%" border="0" cellpadding="5">

      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway</strong></td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><strong>Allowed</strong></td>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Blocking or Accepting Comment</strong></td>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="23%" valign="top"><strong>Pathway 1:</strong> No action - See again</td>
        <td width="6%" align="center" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="allowed" value="0" id="allowed_0" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="comment[]" id="comment_1" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top" class="p1_action"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 2:</strong> See again</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="allowed" value="1" id="allowed_1" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="comment[]" id="comment_2" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top" class="p2_action"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 3:</strong> Refer to ED</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="allowed" value="2" id="allowed_2" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="comment[]" id="comment_3" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top" class="p3_action"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 4:</strong> Refer to Specialist</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top"><input type="radio" name="allowed" value="3" id="allowed_3" /></td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="comment[]" id="comment_4" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="33%" align="left" valign="top"  class="p4_action"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="center" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create Pathways for Level 1" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </form>
```

Comment: What is it that your current code does and you want changed? The first part of your code is very questionable...those `$px_action` lines will set four variables and afterwards you check if either of those are set...this will probably always end up in the first `if` statement.

Comment: Your script seems to be vulnerable to SQL injections via `$action`.

Comment: The code is inserting 4 records into the above table 'pathway'.  This data comes from a form which contains 4 rows, each with a radio button from a radio group and a text area.  The radio button appends a dynamic menu next to the text area in the form row. This menu is allowed for only one row in the form.  The variable $action populates the field 'pathway_action_fk' but all 4 records get the selected value.  I want only the record that has the menu in the form to get the value, otherwise the field retains the default value of '0'..

Comment: @Peter Browne, Give your HTML code as well.

Comment: The $px_action variables are the 4 possible menus added dynamicaly to the form by the user...in effect only one menu can be added, but I needed to be able to append/remove via jquery, hence 4 *possible* menus and IDs that I then need to later check for in PHP..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved this by using

```
$pathway_allowed = intval($_POST['allowed']);
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actions']);


if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$inserted_ids = array();
$pathway_comment = array();

foreach($_POST['comment'] as $comment) {
    $pathway_comment[]= mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
}

for($i=0, $count = count($pathway_comment);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $comment = $pathway_comment[$i];
    $query = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO pathway (             
           pathway_pk,
           case_fk,
           level,
           pathway_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$case_pk',
           '1',
           '%s',
           '$comment')", $pathway_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n');

$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
if ($result) {
$inserted_ids[] = mysql_insert_id();     
 }
}
$query_update = "UPDATE pathway SET pathway_action_fk = '$action' WHERE pathway_pk IN (" . implode(",", $inserted_ids) . ") AND pathway_allowed = 'y'";
$result_update = mysql_query($query_update, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
if($result_update){
$message = "- The pathways for level 1 have been created.";
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After going through your code found that all the four textbox are open and user and insert the text in any of the 4 boxes.

To resolve this use:

```
if ( strlen ( trim ( $comment ) ) > 0 )
{
    //use insert query
}
```

Another way is to provide a checkbox before so use can opt for the option for sending things..

Comment: Users can and must enter a comment in all 4 text areas...only one of these becomes the allowed 'pathway' and this is determined by the radio button next to the text areas.  Clicking thye radio button also shows the actions menu so that the user can select an action for the allowed pathway.