# Update specific record after multiple insert - possibly using last_insert_id()

Tags: php, mysql

I have a multiple insert (4 records) using a for loop. I then want to run an update query on the record that was inserted where pathway_allowed = 'y' (only one of the 4 would have this value).  I guess last_insert_id() would be useful here but not sure how to use this to update that record inserted with the following:

```
$pathway_allowed = intval($_POST['allowed']);
$action = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['actions']);

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$pathway_comment = array();
foreach($_POST['comment'] as $comment) {
    $pathway_comment[]= mysql_real_escape_string($comment);
}
for($i=0, $count = count($pathway_comment);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $comment = $pathway_comment[$i];
    $query = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO pathway (             
           pathway_pk,
           case_fk,
           level,
           pathway_action_fk,
           pathway_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$case_pk',
           '1',
           '$action',
           '%s',
           '$comment')", $pathway_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n');

       $result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
if($result){
- SELECT the 4 records here...
}
}
```

Comment: Peter, you should know that `mysql_query` going to disappear in the future do you know that ? in my answer I have included the `PDO` because you are going to replace your code if PHP 5.5 comes up.. now it's in `PHP 5.5.0 Alpha5 released`. Then if your hosting has this PHP version your code will not be executed. Just to let you know my friend :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each loop iteration, store the `mysql_insert_id()` onto an array, which you can use later to select the new records.  Note, I'm replacing your incremental `for` loop with a tidier `foreach` here:

```
// Initialize arrays for later
// one for the new ids
$inserted_ids = array();
// one to keep comments from failed queries
$failed_comments = array();
// and one for the MySQL errors of failed queries
$errors = array();

foreach ($pathway_comment as $comment) {
    $query = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO pathway (             
           pathway_pk,
           case_fk,
           level,
           pathway_action_fk,
           pathway_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$case_pk',
           '1',
           '$action',
           '%s',
           '$comment')", $pathway_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n');

       $result = mysql_query($query, $connection);

       // If the iteration was successful, save the insert id onto an array
       // but only if $pathway_allowed == 'y'
       if ($result) {
           if ($pathway_allowed == 'y') {
               $inserted_ids[] = mysql_insert_id();        
           }
       }
       // Otherwise, keep an array of comments that failed
       // Maybe useful later if you want to print those that failed
       else {
           $failed_comments[] = $comment;
           // And keep the mysql_error() as well.
           $errors[] = mysql_error();
       }
}
// Loop is done, now you can implode() the inserted ids array:
// These are all ints from an auto_increment PK, so no additional escaping needed
// Execute the query than do whatever you need with the newly inserted rows.
$query = "SELECT * FROM pathway WHERE pathway_pk IN (" . implode(",", $inserted_ids) . ")";
```

You've likely heard this before, but in the long run, consider switching to an API which supports prepared statements, like MySQLi or PDO. You have done all the necessary escaping and integer casting here, but prepared statements can be faster if compiled and executed in a loop, in addition to not requiring escaping.

Comment: Cool, thanks, I'll give it a go.  BTW, I asked this question as a possible way of solving my problem at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15153196/insert-from-for-loop-add-select-option-value-to-only-one-record

Comment: @PeterBrowne I just modified it a bit - didn't notice that you only wanted to save the ones where $pathway_allowed == 'y'

Comment: Not quite, after the insert, I want update one of the four records that were inserted where pathway_allowed = 'y'...

Comment: @PeterBrowne Are you using the updated code? It does that. Only the one where $pathway_allowed = y is added to the `$inserted_ids` array...

Answer (score 1):

> mysql_connect extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in
>   the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension should be used.
>   See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ for more
>   information. Alternatives to this function include: PDO and mysqli_connect()

If you are using PDO you could use this.

```
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=test', 'username', 'password');
```

and in the for loop you do something like this :

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO test (name, email) VALUES(?,?)");
$tmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com'));
$inserted_ids[] = $dbh->lastInsertId();
```

after the loop you will have an array with the 4 inserted ids

Edit: You don't need to reselect values you have entered you can use this

```
IN FOR LOOP
{
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare($query = sprintf("INSERT INTO pathway (pathway_pk,case_fk,level,pathway_action_fk,pathway_allowed, comment)
    VALUES (
       '',
       '$case_pk',
       '1',
       '$action',
       '%s',
       '$comment')", $pathway_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n'););

        // change the values to bindParam 

    $stmt->execute( array('user', 'user@example.com'));
    $data[$i]['pathway_pk'] = $dbh->lastInsertId(); 
    $data[$i]['case_fk'] = $case_pk;
    $data[$i]['level'] = 1;
    $data[$i]['pathway_action_fk'] = $action;
    $data[$i]['pathway_allowed'] = %s;
    $data[$i]['comment'] = $comment;

}
```

then

```
foreach($data as $d){

    echo $d['pathway_pk'];
    echo $d['case_fk'];


}
```